# How market orders are filled?

Tags: trading, stock-markets, markets, bid-ask

When we look at the stock price **S** of a stock, then if I am correct **S** is equal to the average between the highest bid and the lowest ask for this stock. Hence since the highest bid is lower than the lowest ask: we have : **S < lowest ask**

So when I execute a market order, I buy a share of the stock at the price **S**. But then who can sell me this share since **S < lowest ask** no one can sell me a share at a price of **S** ?

So what I don't get is that there is no actually no offer for a price of **S** so when I execute a market order what price do I pay for the share ? The lower ask and not the stock price ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when I execute a market order, I buy a share of the stock at the price S

No, when you place a market buy order, you buy stock at the current (lowest) asking price. The "published" price S can be the last traded price, or the current bid, ask, or midpoint, depending on who is publishing it. Market data aggregators like Google tend to just publish the *last* price, but brokers may publish the ask (or both the bid and the ask) to show you what you can buy the stock for, and analysts may use the midpoint.

Comment: Ok I see thank you. But for example when I type: apple stock price in google, which price is printed ? The midpoint or the last traded price ?

Comment: Most likely it's the last trade - for highly liquid stocks the bid/ask range is very small ,so there should not be much difference between the last price, the midpoint, and the ask.